# How to comment out code in SQLiteStudio SQL editor?

Tags: sqlitestudio

Is there a way to temporary comment out some of code in SQLiteStudio? I have to add `--` or `/* ... */` each time and remove them manually. It will be greate if we can trigger comment using a button or shortcut like `Ctrl-/`. How do you tackle this problem when using SQLiteStudio?

(SQLiteStudio 3.0.7 on Windows 7)

Comment: SQLiteStudio's author here. There's no such shortcut in 3.0.7, but this is a neat feature and I've scheduled it for 3.0.8 to be implemented.

Comment: That's great, next version must be very exciting. Thank you for creating this wonderful software and share it with us!

Answer (score 2):

Now it is available via these notations:

-- for one line comments

/*
    for several
 line comments
*/


Edit:
Ctrl + / : comments the line which cursor is on it, also this hot key adds several line comment notation to the start and end point of selected area.

Comment: Nick asked for a shortcut, not how to comment out ;)